# I cant get this template due to this views.py loop in django

Tags: python, django

I am a new developer in Django type programming. I have a problem with sending this value to the database. What I want to do is the value is dynamically sent from the website then the process of the data will be sent to the database with the models.py in (processing folder) from the views.py(app folder) through forms.py in (processing folder).

this is my code in models.py (processing folder)

```
class Accountdetail(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    position = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    university = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    course = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    secondschool = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    primaryschool = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    aboutme = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
```

this is my form.py(processing folder code)

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import Accountdetail

class AccountForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Accountdetail
    fields = '__all__'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['firstname'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "First Name"
                }
            )
    self.fields['lastname'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Last Name"
                }
            )
    self.fields['address'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Address"
                }
            )
    self.fields['city'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "City"
                }
            )
    self.fields['country'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Country"
                }
            )
    self.fields['postalcode'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Postal Code"
                }
            )
    self.fields['position'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Position"
                }
            )
    self.fields['university'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "University Name"
                }
            )
    self.fields['secondschool'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Secondary School Name"
                }
            )
    self.fields['primaryschool'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Primary School Name"
                }
            )
    self.fields['aboutme'].widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder" : "Describe yourself..."
                }
            )
```

this is my urls.py(processing folder):

```
from django.urls import path
from processing import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('../modification/profile-edit.html', views.updateprofile, name="profileupdate"),
```

this is my urls.py(core folder):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include  # add this

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("authentication.urls")),  # add this
    path("", include("app.urls")),  # add this
    path("", include("processing.urls"))
]
```

The problem is in my views.py in app folder which is this code

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from processing.views import updateprofile

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def pages(request):
    context = {}
    # All resource paths end in .html.
    # Pick out the html file name from the url. And load that template.
    try:

        load_template = request.path.split('/')[-1]
        template = loader.get_template('pages/' + load_template)

        if template == loader.get_template('modification/profile-edit.html'):
            updateprofile(request)

        else:
            pass
    
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

    except:

        template = loader.get_template( 'pages/error-404.html' )
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

please help me how to get that different template I always get the except template whenever I click the button which suppose takes to another template but instead it gives inside the loop template.

Comment: What error do you get? Try to print your traceback in except block.

Comment: We cant guess what the error is. Provide us with some error traceback and we can then help out

Comment: I got this error 

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/%25%20url%20'profileupdate'
Using the URLconf defined in core.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
login/ [name='login']
register/ [name='register']
logout/ [name='logout']
^.*\.html [name='pages']
[name='home']
pages/profile-edit.html [name='profileupdate']
The current path, % url 'profileupdate', didn't match any of these.